# Can pandas do count string typed column on RollingGroupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As per question title. Can pandas do count on string-typed column on RollingGroupby object?

Here's my dataframe:

```
# Let's say my objective is to count the number of unique cars 
# over the last 1 day grouped by park

 park |    date    | to_count
------------------------------
  A   | 2019-01-01 |   Honda
  A   | 2019-01-03 |   Lexus
  A   | 2019-01-05 |   BMW
  A   | 2019-01-05 |   Lexus
  B   | 2019-01-01 |   BMW
  B   | 2019-01-08 |   Lexus
  B   | 2019-01-08 |   Lexus
  B   | 2019-01-10 |   Ford
```

Here's what I want:

```
 park |    date    | unique_count
----------------------------------
  A   | 2019-01-01 |      1
  A   | 2019-01-03 |      1
  A   | 2019-01-05 |      2
  B   | 2019-01-01 |      1
  B   | 2019-01-08 |      1
  B   | 2019-01-10 |      1

# Bit of explanation:
# There are 2 type of cars coming to park A over last 1 day on 5th Jan so distinct count is 2.
# There are 2 cars of 1 type (Lexus) coming to park B over last 1 day on 8th Jan so distinct count is 1.
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initiate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'park': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-05',
             '2019-01-01', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-10'],
    'to_count': ['Honda', 'Lexus', 'BMW', 'Lexus', 'BMW', 'Lexus', 'Lexus', 'Ford']
})

# string to date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# group. This is more intuitive to me but sadly this does not work.
unique_count = df.groupby('park').rolling('1d', on='date').to_count.nunique()

# factorize then group. This works (but why???)
df['factorized'] = pd.factorize(df.to_count)[0]
unique_count = df.groupby('park').rolling('1d', on='date').factorized.apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)) )

result = unique_count.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['park', 'date'], keep='last')
```

Here's my environment:

- Mac 10.12 High Sierra
- python3.6
- pandas 0.22.0

**To emphasize, I need the rolling window function to work. In this example, the window happens to be 1 day, but I might want it to work for 3 days, 7 days, 2 hours, 5 seconds.**

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['park','date'])['to_count'].nunique().reset_index()`

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I need the rolling window

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
- first, group the data frame by `park` and `date`
- aggregate `to_count` by its number of unique values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'park': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-05',
             '2019-01-01', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-10'],
    'to_count': ['Honda', 'Lexus', 'BMW', 'Lexus', 'BMW', 'Lexus', 'Lexus', 'Ford']
})

agg_df = df.groupby(by=['park', 'date']).agg({'to_count': pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()
```

Comment: I need the rolling window function. not just group it. I can group it just fine. THis will not work if I change the window date into 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not terribly pythonic, but gets the job done I think.

One park at a time, I sliced the dataframe offsetting by days (adjust the days to get your rolling amount), and then retrieving the cars values into a list.

Working with the cars in a list for each day, we can calculate the total unique cars per day.

The result is a list, which you could convert to a dataframe if you need to.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# initiate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'park': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-05',
             '2019-01-01', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-10'],
    'to_count': ['Honda', 'Lexus', 'BMW', 'Lexus', 'BMW', 'Lexus', 'Lexus', 'Ford']
})
# string to date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

result = []
for park in ['A', 'B']:
    # Do one park at a time
    df_park = df[df['park'] == park][['date','to_count']]
    df_park.set_index('date',inplace=True)
    # interate through the dataframe and put results to list.
    for i, v in df_park.iterrows(): 
        # THIS IS YOUR ROLLING VALUE IN DAYS
        days = 1
        # create the starting date
        b = i - datetime.timedelta(days=days)
        # create a list of cars during the period
        li = df_park.loc[b:i].values
        # reduce the list to unique cars
        unique_cars = len(np.unique(li))
        # append the results to the result list
        result.append((park, i.strftime('%B %d, %Y'), unique_cars))

# the final list has duplicates, so use set to drop the dups and re-sort for the result.
sorted(list(set(result)))
```

Result looks like this:

```
[('A', 'January 01, 2019', 1),
('A', 'January 03, 2019', 1),
('A', 'January 05, 2019', 2),
('B', 'January 01, 2019', 1),
('B', 'January 08, 2019', 1),
('B', 'January 10, 2019', 1)]
```

Comment: I notice in your question now that you might want to slice by hours as well. You will have to make minor adjustment to my answer which is using only dates, not hours.